# Is this the right solution for an unsolvable system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I have to find the values of $k$ such that this system $\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
      1&0&-3&-3\\
      2&k&-1&-2\\
1&2&k&1
    \end{array}
\right]$ is:

a) unsolvable  b) solvable with infinite solutions c) one solution.

After some steps we can see in this matrix $\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
      1&0&-3&-3\\
      0&k&5&4\\
0&2&k+3&4
    \end{array}
\right]$ for $k=2$ the second and the thrid row are the same, so if the substract them on row becomes all zeros. (And the system is unsolvable)

The next step: $\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|cc}
      1&0&-3&-3\\
      0&k&5&4\\
0&0&k^2-7&4k-8
    \end{array}
\right]$ now im not that sure but I think, the solutions to $k^2-7=0$ should be the values of $k$ such that there are infinite solutions.

Then every possbile value k besides 2 and the solutions for $k^2-7=0$ would return a solvable system with one solution?

Comment: @Moo what should this tell me? And does trying the RREF for k = -5 mean to insert -5 as k in the last matrix?

Comment: I see, because division with zero is prohibited -5 is another solution. Are those two all or are there others? How to know for sure that I found all? Is the rest correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the system has no/infinite or unique solutions if the determinant of the system is zero or nonzero. The determinant is:
$$k^2+3k-10.$$
Thus:
$$k^2+3k-10=0 \Rightarrow k_1=-5 \ (\text{no}); k_2=2 \ (\text{infinite}).$$
For $k\ne -5;2$ there is a unique solution.

Comment: Is there a way to determinate which solution is for no and which is for infinite? So all numberse beside 2 and -5 for k will give me an unique solution?

Answer (score 0):

from the first equation we get
$$x_1=-3+3x_3$$
plugging this in the second equation and solving for $x_3$ we have
$$x_3=\frac{4}{5}-\frac{k}{5}x_2$$
and for the third equation we get
$$x_2\left(2-\frac{k}{3}(3+k)\right)=4-\frac{4}{5}(3+k)$$
can you finish?
from the last equation we get
$$x_2(6-3k-k^2)=\frac {3}{5}(8-4k)$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what to do with this. Should I try to remove all the variables from the equations to check with which k x1 to x3 gets zero?

Answer (score 0):

After the first step you should consider $k=0$, in which case there is a unique solution, just plug in $k=0$.

If in your second step, if $k=\pm\sqrt7$, the system has no solution because for these values $4k-8\neq0$.